# Snippet for generating public variables in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

```
private float _speed = 5;

public float Speed => _speed;
```

I'm trying to make it so I can generate the public reference to a private variable like this with a snippet but is proving to be a bit more challenging than I thought it would be.

In theory it would just be replacing private with public, removing the "_", making the first letter UpperCase and refencing it with =>

*To clarity more, I would like to either type on the variable and generate a Public SameType MyVar => _myVar, or be able to create them togethor by just creating the private one, say Private Type _myVar; tab tab auto creates Public Type MyVar => _myVar

**On my case, this is for Unity development, I use [SerializeField] before the private variables so they show up in the inspector and their values can be set there, so I do need the private one so other scripts cant modify the value and a public one or a method to reference it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're facing, what you have attempted so far, and the question?

Comment: Look at the contents of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\prop.snippet` which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @John Not really. If I understand correctly, the OP wants to type the first line and then use _that_ to generate the second.

Comment: put your cursor on `_speed` and press `Ctrl-.` to select the **Encapsulate Property** refactoring then.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes! thats exactly it. I dont think the encapsulate is gonna help much in my case.

Comment: @ArthurSousa Why not? That seems to do (almost) exactly what you want (except that you have to manually remove the setter). There's even a [keyboard shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#bkmk_refactor-global-shortcuts) for that action. Your other option is to use an auto-property with a private setter.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah actually this is probably the best I'm gonna get! gotta remove the set as you said but is not the end of the world, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's not what snippets are for, they're templates that you can fill in yourself and that don't rely on other code. What you're asking for is more the job of Roslyn code fixer providers.

That said, that entire chunk of code is an anti-pattern, use auto-properties instead, that's what they're there for:

```
public float Speed { get; } = 5;
```

Comment: Should probably use `private set;` in this case.

Comment: On my case, this is for Unity development, I use  [SerializeField] before the private variables so they show up in the inspector and their values can be set there, so I do need the private one so other scripts cant modify the value and a public one or a method to reference it

Comment: @Arthur In that case (and if you're using C# 9 or above), you could use a property with an [init-only setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) instead: `public float Speed { get; init; } = 5;`.

Comment: There are reasons for creating the backing variable manually.

Comment: Sure, there's plenty of bad reasons to do the wrong thing.